# How to determine the .NET platform that runs the .NET Standard class library?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

[.NET Standard Library — One library to rule them all.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/)

The .NET Standard Library functionality may vary depending on the .NET platform that runs it:

- .NET Framework
- .NET Core
- Xamarin

How to check the .NET platform where the .NET Standard library currently runs?

For example:

```
// System.AppContext.TargetFrameworkName 
// returns ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" for .NET Framework 
// and
// returns null for .NET Core.

if (IsNullOrWhiteSpace(System.AppContext.TargetFrameworkName))
    // the platform is .NET Core or at least not .NET Framework
else
    // the platform is .NET Framework
```

Is it reliable way to answer the question (at least for .NET Framework and .NET Core)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation.frameworkdescription(v=vs.110).aspx) Property from the `System.Runtime.InteropServices` namespace.

> Returns a string that indicates the name of the .NET installation on which an app is running.
>
> The property returns one of the following strings:
>
> - ".NET Core".
> - ".NET Framework".
> - ".NET Native".

Comment: probably want to check this w/ `Contains` because for .NET Framework 4.8 at least it returns the full version info ie. `.NET Framework 4.8.4420.0`

Answer (score 4):

Well.. one of the [main ideas behind .NET Standard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt842506.aspx) is that unless you're developing a very specific cross-platform library then in general you should not be caring what the underlying runtime implementation is.

But if you really must then one way of overriding that principle is this:

```
public enum Implementation { Classic, Core, Native, Xamarin }

public Implementation GetImplementation()
{
   if (Type.GetType("Xamarin.Forms.Device") != null)
   {
      return Implementation.Xamarin;
   }
   else
   {
      var descr = RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription;
      var platf = descr.Substring(0, descr.LastIndexOf(' '));
      switch (platf)
      {
         case ".NET Framework":
            return Implementation.Classic;
         case ".NET Core":
            return Implementation.Core;
         case ".NET Native":
            return Implementation.Native;
         default:
            throw new ArgumentException();
      }
   }
}
```

And if you want to be even more egregious, then you can bring in the different values for [Xamarin.Forms.Device.RuntimePlatform](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Device.RuntimePlatform/) also (with more details [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/device/)).