# Determine the framework in a .NET Standard DLL at runtime

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard, .net-framework-version

In a .NET Standard project is there a way to determine if the DLL is run in .NET Core or the regular .NET Framework at runtime?

I want to handle things differently for different .NET platforms.

Comment: Does this help with what you need? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.version(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine the .NET platform that runs the .NET Standard class library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48259320/)

Comment: Seems to be an duplicate but the answer from saul is outdated since Environment.Version no longer returns null in core.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [**RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation.frameworkdescription(v=vs.110).aspx) Property from the `System.Runtime.InteropServices` namespace.

> Returns a string that indicates the name of the .NET installation on which an app is running.
>
> The property returns one of the following strings:
>
> - ".NET Core".
> - ".NET Framework".
> - ".NET Native".